# How to get data from multiple columns and save it in a list using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need help to get data from some columns into a list.

Lets say I have this `test.txt` file

```
30012    820202    999201
81910    882101    100291
88271    003300    221920
93929    719300
```

I want to save data from even and odd columns in a seperate list.

I tried with the following but did not get the right answer that I want.

```
import pandas as pd

fileRead = pd.read_fwf("test.txt", delim_whitespace = True, header=None, dtype=object)

indx = 0
for indx in range(len(fileRead.columns)):
    if indx % 2 == 1:
        channel1 = fileRead[indx].tolist()

    else:
        channel0 = fileRead[indx].tolist()

print "CH0:" + channel0
print "CH1:" + channel1
```

This produced

```
CH1: ['820202', '882101', '003300', '719300']
CH0: ['999201', '100291', '221920', nan]
```

My desired result is

```
CH1: ['820202', '882101', '003300', '719300']
CH0: ['30012','81910','88271','93929','999201', '100291', '221920', nan]
```

What did I miss in this script? Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: Some problem? Solution does not work?

Comment: at first it worked but when I tried to add more column, the result shows that it did not print the first column. I add new column to make it 6 instead 3 like in the question. Sorry for untick.

Comment: Hmmmm, so first column is omited? Maybe first column if converted to `index`, you can check it by `print (df.index)`. If yes, solution is very easy - `a = df.reset_index().values` instead `a = df.values`

Comment: I check by `print df.index` and it shows `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')`. What I understand it has 4 row here right?

Comment: yes, and it is default order ant there are `4` rows. Now it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `df` to `arrays` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), then select columns and use [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) for flattening. Last call `tolist`:

```
a = df.values
ch0 = a[:, ::2].ravel().tolist()
ch1 = a[:, 1::2].ravel().tolist()
print (ch0)
['30012', '999201', '81910', '100291', '88271', '221920', '93929', nan]

print (ch1)
['820202', '882101', '003300', '719300']
```

Comment: sorry for unaccept this comment before, I figure out that last error. It is just my typo. Sorry again. Thank you for your help

Comment: No problem, glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
You can use `iloc`

```
ch0 = fileRead.iloc[:, 0::2].stack().tolist()
ch1 = fileRead.iloc[:, 1::2].stack().tolist()
```

Instead of `stack` I could have used `numpy`'s `ravel`.  However, I decided to use stack in order to take advantage of it's implicit `dropna`.  This relies more heavily on `pandas`' api and is more transparent.

---

**Option 2**
We could rely on `numpy` more with

```
v = fileRead.values

ch0 = v[:, 0::2].ravel()
ch0 = ch0[~np.isnan(ch0)].tolist()

ch1 = v[:, 1::2].ravel()
ch1 = ch1[~np.isnan(ch1)].tolist()
```

---

```
ch0

['30012', '999201', '81910', '100291', '88271', '221920', '93929']
```

---

```
ch1

['820202', '882101', '003300', '719300']
```